# pthread_create() invokes the function the thread points to?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

As the title says, when `pthread_create()` is invoked, the created thread executes automatically the function it points to or after the creation of the thread you must write a piece of code that invokes the given function?

Answer (score 4):

If successful, `pthread_create` has arranged that the thread start routine will eventually run.  There is no separate start function you need to call, unlike in Java or Python.  Exactly when the thread start routine begins execution is of course unspecified: this can happen before or after `pthread_create` returns, and vary from one `pthread_create` call to the next.

For some related discussion, see the [Rationale under `pthread_create`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html#tag_16_424_08) in POSIX.